# Tcpdf pdf file does not download

Tags: php, tcpdf

When I click on the link where TCPDF api is used. This link opens the new tab a open and the download link shows but the file size does not show. And did not download the file.

```
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {

public function Header() {

$image_file = 'images/logo.png';
$this->Image($image_file, 10, 10, null, null, 'PNG', '', 'T', false, 300, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
$this->SetFont('', 'B', 20);
$this->Cell(0, 15, 'Global Tours Center', 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'M', 'M');

}
public function Footer() {

$this->SetY(-15);
$this->SetFont('', 'I', 8);
$this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');

}

}
ob_clean();
$pdf = new MYPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Hamaad');
$pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 006');
$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, 40, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER); 
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {

require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);

}
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('times', '', 10);
$html = "here is my html code";
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
$pdf->lastPage();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$pdf->Output('ticket.pdf', 'I');
```

Please guide me i stuck on this point. What to do how to do.

[image]

Comment: Did you solved it? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run this code, and it work with me:
firstly, you should include the file includes/tcpdf/tcpdf.php
secondly, you should be sure that logo image file already exist: $image_file = 'images/logo.png';

this code run with me:

```
<?php
require_once("../include.inc.php");
require_once (MAIN_DOCUMENT_ROOT . "/includes/tcpdf/config/lang/ara.php");
require_once (MAIN_DOCUMENT_ROOT . "/includes/tcpdf/tcpdf.php");

class MYPDF extends TCPDF {

public function Header() {

//$image_file = 'images/logo.png';
//$this->Image($image_file, 10, 10, null, null, 'PNG', '', 'T', false, 300, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
$this->SetFont('', 'B', 20);
$this->Cell(0, 15, 'Global Tours Center', 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'M', 'M');

}
public function Footer() {

$this->SetY(-15);
$this->SetFont('', 'I', 8);
$this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');

}

}
ob_clean();
$pdf = new MYPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Hamaad');
$pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 006');
$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, 40, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER); 
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {

require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);

}
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('times', '', 10);
$html = "here is my html code";
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
$pdf->lastPage();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$pdf->Output('ticket.pdf', 'I');
```